# FusionAUth : How to merge user signup + sign in FusionAuth, to make user Auto login to web application

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, oauth, jwt, fusionauth

We are trying FusionAuth & looking to have a single step flow for Sign up + Sign In.
After user signs up, we want to show/land him directly to our application's dashboard page (without showing him login page in between the flow). The authentication should happen but internally i.e we are expecting OAuth2 standard IdToken in response to "WebApplication" so that web application can use IdToken to allow user to application.

Please note that we don't want to use approaches where we need to pass Username/password to our web application, don't want to handle user credentials. Also that we dont want to use Authentication Tokens returned in Registration flow because AuthenticationTokens are not that secure, looking to use OAuth2 based IdToken instead.

I have came across this post "https://fusionauth.io/community/forum/topic/165/taking-a-user-directly-to-the-registration-page/3" and tried following request, but it is showing Login page instead of registration.

/oauth2/register?client_id=<Configured_client_id>&redirect_uri=<Configured_redirect_uri>&response_type=code

(I have not used CSRF parameter though)
Please can you suggest why its showing Login Page?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to have a user register and be sent directly to your application, as long as you set the correct redirect_uri and put that on the registration URL:

`https://local.fusionauth.io/oauth2/register?client_id=c50329fa-93e5-4618-8d9f-73d0ab069a23&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fapp.example.com%2F`

The application will then receive a code that can be exchanged for an access token. You can call the userinfo endpoint with that token and get user information like email address, etc.

What you won't get that it seems like you might want is an id token. For that you'll have to send the user through the login process with a scope of `profile`. However, you could mind your own 'id token'-lite using the values from the userinfo endpoint and the JWT vending: https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/apis/jwt/#vend-a-jwt